# clearRect coordinates not matching mouse position on scaled canvas

Tags: javascript, css, canvas

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

  canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d'),
  img = new Image;

  img.onload = draw;
  img.src = 'http://fariskassim.com/stage/strip/v3/img/before1.jpg';

  function draw() {
      //drawImageProp(ctx, this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      drawImageProp(ctx, this, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height, 0.1, 0.5);
  }


  ERASE_W=150;
  ERASE_H=70;
  rzr=$("#razor2");
  RAZOR_W=rzr.width();
  RAZOR_H=rzr.height();
  

/**
 * By Ken Fyrstenberg Nilsen
 *
 * drawImageProp(context, image [, x, y, width, height [,offsetX, offsetY]])
 *
 * If image and context are only arguments rectangle will equal canvas
*/
function drawImageProp(ctx, img, x, y, w, h, offsetX, offsetY) {

    if (arguments.length === 2) {
        x = y = 0;
        w = ctx.canvas.width;
        h = ctx.canvas.height;
    }

    /// default offset is center
    offsetX = typeof offsetX === 'number' ? offsetX : 0.5;
    offsetY = typeof offsetY === 'number' ? offsetY : 0.5;

    /// keep bounds [0.0, 1.0]
    if (offsetX < 0) offsetX = 0;
    if (offsetY < 0) offsetY = 0;
    if (offsetX > 1) offsetX = 1;
    if (offsetY > 1) offsetY = 1;

    var iw = img.width,
        ih = img.height,
        r = Math.min(w / iw, h / ih),
        nw = iw * r,   /// new prop. width
        nh = ih * r,   /// new prop. height
        cx, cy, cw, ch, ar = 1;

    /// decide which gap to fill    
    if (nw < w) ar = w / nw;
    if (nh < h) ar = h / nh;
    nw *= ar;
    nh *= ar;

    /// calc source rectangle
    cw = iw / (nw / w);
    ch = ih / (nh / h);

    cx = (iw - cw) * offsetX;
    cy = (ih - ch) * offsetY;

    /// make sure source rectangle is valid
    if (cx < 0) cx = 0;
    if (cy < 0) cy = 0;
    if (cw > iw) cw = iw;
    if (ch > ih) ch = ih;

    /// fill image in dest. rectangle
    ctx.drawImage(img, cx, cy, cw, ch,  x, y, w, h);
}


});





var hand = $('#razor2')[0];
(function() {


    var origin = {
      x: $(window).height(),
      y: $(window).width()
    }

    window.onmousemove = handleMouseMove;
    function handleMouseMove(event) {
        event = event || window.event; // IE-ism
        // event.clientX and event.clientY contain the mouse position
        hand.style.left = event.clientX-92+"px";
        hand.style.top = event.clientY-5+"px";
        var leftSide = false;
        var d = {
          x: origin.x - event.clientX,
          y: origin.y - event.clientY
        };

        var angle = Math.atan2(d.x, d.y) * 90 / Math.PI * -1;
        if (leftSide) {
          //angle = angle * -1;
        }
        hand.style["-webkit-transform"] = "rotate("+parseInt(angle,10)+"deg)";
        hand.style["transform"] = "rotate("+parseInt(angle,10)+"deg)";
    }
})();

function erase(e){
   var cvxw = ctx.canvas.width;
   var parentOffset = $("#razor2").parent().offset(); 
   //or $(this).offset(); if you really just want the current element's offset
   var relX = e.pageX +  0;
   var relY = e.pageY + 0;
  
ctx.clearRect((relX-(RAZOR_W/2)),(relY-(RAZOR_H/2)),ERASE_W,ERASE_H);
}

function draw_razor(e){
  var parentOffset = $("#razor2").parent().offset(); 
   //or $(this).offset(); if you really just want the current element's offset
   var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
   var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
  
  rzr.show();

  rzr.css('margin-top','-'+(RAZOR_H/2)+'px');
  rzr.css('margin-left','-'+(RAZOR_W/2)+'px');
  
  
  rzr.css('left',relX+'px');
  rzr.css('top',relY+'px');
};


$(document).mousemove(function(e){
  draw_razor(e);
});

$('#razor2').bind('mousedown', function(e){
    $('#razor2').bind('mousemove', function(e){
        erase(e);
        hand.className = "active";
    });

    $('#razor2').bind('mouseup',function(){
        $('#razor2').unbind('mousemove')
        hand.className = "";
    });
});

$('#razor2').on('dragstart', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();                                       
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#game {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100vw;
  font-size: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  box-shadow: 3px 3px 7px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.8);
  margin:0;
  overflow:hidden;
}

body {
  background-color: navajo;
  background-position: center top;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  margin:0;
}

.canvas_wrap {
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  position:relative;
  overflow: hidden;
}

canvas {
  /*cursor: none;*/
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 3;
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}

#kitten{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left: 0;
  z-index: 2;
}

#razor2 {
  background-image:url(http://fariskassim.com/stage/strip/v3/img/razor.png);
  /*cursor: none;*/
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 98;
  width: 800px;
  height: 476px;
  margin-top: -200px !important;
  margin-left: -200px !important; 
  background-size: cover;
  object-position: -99999px 99999px;
}
#razor2.active {
    background-position: 0 100% !important;
}

#razor {
  height: 0;
  width: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="game">
  <img id="razor" src="img/razor.png">
  <div id="razor2"></div>
  <div class="canvas_wrap">
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1730" height="870">Los ti browser!</canvas>
    <img id="kitten" src="http://fariskassim.com/stage/strip/v3/img/after1.jpg">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you'll see, when you start dragging your mouse across the canvas, you'll see that the `clearRect` (shaving hair) is not taking place on the mouse position. its a little off to the left

i believe this is because i scaled the canvas to make it responsive.

Anyone knows how i modify my code to make the `clearRect` work on the position of the mouse?

Comment: why still using fiddle? SO have internal code editor & tester as I've edited before...

Comment: reverted back to it

Comment: nice... since not all people can opening other site (with some reasons).. Like me, on my office has lot limitation to access much sites.. so, the best way is using SO capabilities...

Comment: Scaling a canvas via CSS does not change its pixel coordinate system. So naturally, you need to apply the reverse scaling to your mouse coordinates, to translate them into the correct pixel values in regard to the canvas’ coordinate system.

Comment: i see. could you perhaps show me an example? point me at something in my code to change maybe

Comment: @CBroe. Geek speak alert on your comment! :-p In simpler terms, if you scale the canvas by 2X then you must multiple both your mouse event x,y and your `clearRect` width and height by 2 to properly clear the scaled drawing.

Comment: @markE: Not multiply by, but divide by - as I so geek-spoke before, you need to _reverse_ the transformation. Say canvas has an actual width of 200 pixels, and you scale it up by 2, then it covers 400 "screen" pixels. Move your mouse cursor to the exact center, then it will report that the position is 200 (screen) pixels from the left side of the canvas. But we know our canvas is only 200px wide, so the middle is at a 100px (both times canvas pixels) - so we need to take the 200 "screen" pixels of the cursor position, and divide them by the scaling factor of 2, to get 100 canvas pixels.

Comment: @CBroe. Yep, I stand corrected :-)) Should be divide not multiply. Sadly, that's not the first time my mind has played that exact same trick on me. Thanks for the second pair of eyes!